# Рекурсия, именновая функция и Function Expression

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть код:

```
SomeObj.prototype.someLongFuncName = function (x) {
    // some code
    var x = x - 1;
    SomeObj.prototype.someLongFuncName(x);
}
```

arguments.callee мы не используем потому что в теме.

Вопрос: нормально ли использовать в Function Expression именнованную функцию с коротким именем для удобного вызова как ниже:

```
SomeObj.prototype.someLongFuncName = function f(x) {
    // some code
    var x = x - 1;
    f(x);
}
```

Comment: Лично я, всегда использую второй вариант. Чтоб самому не запутаться, спустя время, всегда называю функцию thisFn.

Comment: Вопрос немного не в этом, вопрос в том как это расценивается с точки зрения качества кода, кул или не кул ))

Comment: Конечно этот вариант лучше, чем писать "полное имя". Рекурсия будет работать всегда, даже если вам захочется переименовать someLongFuncName на someLongAndCoolFuncName. Глобальная область видимости, при таком наименовании, не засоряется. Короче, очень даже кул)

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта плохи.

Если не используется `this` внутри функции прототипа, то и добавлять в прототип нет надобности. В этом случае обычное объявление функции и обычный же вызов вполне подойдут.

Если же `this` используется - то в обоих случаях будет ошибка при заходе в рекурсию, так как в первом случае `this` поменяется на объект прототипа, вместо основного объекта, а во втором - `this` станет глобальным объектом.

---

Таким образом для корректного вызова функции следует использовать `this`.

Первый случай:

```
SomeObj.prototype.someLongFuncName = function (x) {
    if(condition) return; // чтобы не было бесконечной рекурсии.
    // some code
    var x = x - 1;
    this.someLongFuncName(x);
}
```

Второй случай

```
SomeObj.prototype.someLongFuncName = function f(x) {
    if(condition) return; // чтобы не было бесконечной рекурсии.
    // some code
    var x = x - 1;
    f.call(this,x); // устанавливаем нужное значение `this` в вызываемой функции.
}
```